# How to decode apple sign-in id_token in token response

Tags: c#, .net, apple-sign-in

I followed the following blog [post](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Implementing-Sign-In-with-Apple-in-ASPNET-Core) to implement Apple sign-in. It was written long time ago when there was no id_token with user info. When I request token API I receive JSON with several fields. The question is how to decode data in id_token field to get email address and user id.

Comment: Use a JWT library.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Dai,

Turns out to be quite easy:

```
var responseJSON = JObject.Parse(appleTokenResponseString);
var id_token = responseJSON.GetValue("id_token").ToString();
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();   
var jwt = handler.ReadJwtToken(id_token);
foreach (var claim in jwt.Claims)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{claim.Type}:{claim.Value}");
}
```